# Nextjs with sass styling throws error only in first run after npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

Using nextjs with sass styling shows weird error on only first run after running npm run dev. after refreshing page or going back and forward with links in my pages works fine.
error which i get is " cannot read property 'call' of undefined".
if i run project with `npm run build` then `npm start` (production mode) works fine too.

Comment: Add error, add code

Comment: We need to see that "weird error" and your code first.